# одновременный Hover ефект

Tags: css3, html5, hover

Народ подскажите: как сделать ефект hover когда наводиш мышкой на БЛОК(DIV на рисунке) h3 и span меняют цвет одновременно[image: картинка с структурой HTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
блок:ховер спан,
блок:ховер что угодно{
  стили какие угодно здесь
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало :)

Comment: галочку рядом тыкни с ответом